# Create binary file of specific length

Tags: terminal, osx, command

I wish to run a command which will create a binary file where the length of the file is specified on issuing the command.

Answer (score 6):

If you have the `truncate` command then this can be used to create a file of any size:

eg

```
% truncate -s 8192 foo
% ls -l foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 sweh sweh 8192 Aug 21 16:01 foo
```

If you don't have that then you can use the `dd` command to do similar:

```
% dd if=/dev/zero of=bar bs=1c count=0 seek=8192   
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 0.000116926 s, 0.0 kB/s

% ls -l bar
-rw-r--r-- 1 sweh sweh 8192 Aug 21 16:04 bar
```

In both cases this will create a "sparse" file, if the filesystem supports it.

If you want a file to take up the space then specifying a `count` and no `seek`

```
% dd if=/dev/zero of=bar bs=1c count=10000000
```

This can be slow, so sometimes it's worth doing things in larger chunks. eg to create a 10M file with the space allocated

```
% dd if=/dev/zero of=bar bs=1M count=10
```